# Power Automate: Unable to add action after every approve response from a dynamic list of approvers inside an approval workflow

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

Hi I need help building a flow for a list of approvers, the list is dynamic and I am reading it from an SQL table,

the problem is I am unable to update a row in SQL upon approval of each approver, I want to update the workflow table to change the status of the approval of this user, but I am unable to find a solution for this.

I tried 1 signle workflow at first, but then realized there is no valid way to apply any action after 1 person approves his action / while the approval workflow is running. (If there is please tell me)

So, I tried to use Apply To Each for the list of approvers, but even the apply to each doesn't continue to the next actions inside it if it contains a running approval workflow, see the screenshot below, note that I am building the approval sequentially here which means a separate workflow for each user which I didn't like but because the "everyone must approve" single workflow wasn't working for me.

[image]

Can someone explain if I'm missing anything here or there is a straightforward method to apply an action after each approval response without needing to wait all the workflow to finish?

For example: I want to add action "Execute a SQL query" during the approval of each user, let's say we have user1 and user2 as approvers, I want to perform that "Execute" action when user1 clicks on approve without waiting the entire workflow to end, is there a straightforward way for this?